# wxWidgets/wxPython - App Freezes After Scrolling A Window Filled With Text Sized With GridSizer

Tags: wxpython, scrollbar, wxwidgets

So basically I have made a very simple wxPython app, which combines the ScrolledWindow and Gridsizers. 
It has your average Frame, a panel and a ScrolledWindow. Within this ScrollWindow, I managed to add a lot of tables with the help of GridSizers. The layout is fine, and resizes fine as well, though a bit slower but that's expected. When I scroll very slowly, it all still works. But when I scroll fast, it does react to scrolling, even continuous scrolling and loads all the elements well. But as soon as I scroll to much and move my mouse of out the scroll window and I want to resize or move the panel, the app itself and all other apps freeze!

So I condensed the code even further to not build the tables I wanted for my main app, but simply populate the grids with 1000 statictext strings. The problem still persists. Even when I write the same snippet of code in C++ and build it with Visual Studio, the problem becomes even worse, despite it being compiled! It took 1m30s to load the program and in the meantime freezes all the other programs as well. 
I did manage to load the task manager and noticed that it uses only 7 MB RAM and negligible amount of processing power, despite it freezing.
I feel like there's something to do with events: the more I scroll, the more " things" are put into some queue which gets executed the moment I move my mouse out of the window.

Here's the code. First it will create your wx.Frame, then the panel. The scrolled window is given the panel as the parent, and the vertical scroll rate is set to 20. The virtual size is unspecified, but this will be recalculated when it's fit to the sizers. Then a 10x100 gridsizer is made, and filled with statictexts containing "test". This grid is then set to the ScrolledWindows' panel, so the text is displayed nicely within the scrollwindow. Finally, the scrollwindow is added to the main sizer to fit it in the entire app.

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, title='Test.py')

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        cols = 10
        rows = 100

        scrollWin = wx.ScrolledWindow(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(400, 400))
        scrollWin.SetScrollbars(0, 20, 0, 0)

        grid = wx.GridSizer(rows, cols, (5,5))

        texts = [wx.StaticText(scrollWin, wx.ID_STATIC, 'Test') for i in range(rows*cols)]
        for text in texts:
            grid.Add(text, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        scrollWin.SetSizer(grid)
        grid.Fit(scrollWin)

        topSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        topSizer.Add(scrollWin, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        panel.SetSizer(topSizer)
        topSizer.Fit(self)
        topSizer.SetSizeHints(self)

        self.Show()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyForm()
app.MainLoop()
```

The last thing I would expect the bottleneck to be is scrolling the program's window, but more the resizing of the app.

Again, I can still scroll around a bit, even frantically, but when I move my mouse out of the window it freezes. I believe it doesn't have much to do with the resizing of the grids, but with some unknown background event handling which needed to be caught up. Thanks for your time, any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the exact source of slowdown in your case, it does seem strange that this wouldn't work. However it's something you shouldn't try doing in the first place anyhow. Under MSW, there is a limit of 10000 windows per process and a limit of 32700 windows per system. Consuming 1000 of them is just not a good idea.

You should use `wxGrid` instead, which doesn't create a window per each cell -- this is simply too expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I pretty much dropped using the wx window elements for my main purpose: creating some simple, slightly fancy, tables to display data and having them resize upon window resizing using Gridsizers. For this I just wrote some HTML code and have it load in my browser. It works flawlessly in the browser, but not in wx. The wxPython HTMLwindow jitters a bit as if the page loading frame rate can't catch with the scrolling. 
Eitherway, still weird the main issue persists since it's not the resizing that's the problem but the scrolling.

Comment: FWIW browsers don't use native controls, i.e. they do the same thing `wxGrid` does.